# Unable to override swipe to delete cell functionality for iOS v > 6.1

Tags: ipad, uitableview, ios7, uiswipegesturerecognizer

We are developing an iPad application where entire UI is created using Storyboard file.

In one of the view controller scene, there is a UITableView which contains a custom cell.

When I swipe to the table cell, a delete button appears for that.

How to disable this swipe to delete functionality. We have our own Edit button on top navigation bar, which sets UITableView's editingMode. We require to disable swipe to delete funcitonality.

Here is what we have already tried:

**1. Overriden swipe gesture method:**

> ```
>  UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureR = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
>                                              initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
>  [gestureR setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];//|UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
>  [myTableView addGestureRecognizer:gestureR];
> ```

We have tried this gesture with both, myTableView as well in CustomCell file.

**2. Remove swipe gesture method:**

```
  UIGestureRecognizer* swipe = [[self.tableView gestureRecognizers] objectAtIndex:2];
    [myTableView removeGestureRecognizer:swipe];
```

Both of those code blocks are not working for us.

This issue is there only for the iOS 7 only, as there is default swipe to delete given for UITableView.

Please suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1.) is not really an override. It seems adding multiple recognisers could have undefined results.
(2.) looks like a private API hack, so also not advisable.

Instead, the editing behaviour of a table view is controlled by overriding these methods:

```
- tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:
– tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW24) for details.